# calculating Levenshtein Distance using word lists

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

first i want to say that i am a newbie in python. I trying to calculate the Levenshtein Distance for many lists of word. Until now i succeed writing the code for a pair of word, but i'm having some problems doing it for lists. I just habe two lists with words one below the other like this:
carlos
stiv
peter

I want to use the Levenshtein distance for a similarity approach. Could somebady tell me how i can load the lists and then use a function to calculate de distance?

I'll appreciated!

Here is my code just for two strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-

def lev_dist(source, target):
    if source == target:
        return 0

#words = open(test_file.txt,'r').read().split();

    # Prepare matrix
    slen, tlen = len(source), len(target)
    dist = [[0 for i in range(tlen+1)] for x in range(slen+1)]
    for i in xrange(slen+1):
        dist[i][0] = i
    for j in xrange(tlen+1):
        dist[0][j] = j

    # Counting distance
    for i in xrange(slen):
        for j in xrange(tlen):
            cost = 0 if source[i] == target[j] else 1
            dist[i+1][j+1] = min(
                            dist[i][j+1] + 1,   # deletion
                            dist[i+1][j] + 1,   # insertion
                            dist[i][j] + cost   # substitution
                        )
    return dist[-1][-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print 'Usage: You have to enter a source_word and a target_word'
        sys.exit(-1)
    source, target = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    print lev_dist(source, target)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Compute the distance for each pair in the list?

Comment: Step 1.  Add code to read your list (or is it two lists?).  Step 2.  Add a loop to iterate through your list (or is it two lists?).  Step 3.  Post the new code so we can comment on it.  The code you posted is good, but you need to write the next two parts, also.

Comment: Thans for the fast answers.
Larsmans: i want to compute the distance for each word from one list to every word of the second list.

S.Lott: there are two lists!

Comment: Any ideas how can i do it with two lists?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally got the code working with some help from a friend :)
You can compute the Levenshtein distance and compare it to every word from the second list changing the last line in the script, i.e: print(list1[0], list2[i]), to compare the first word from the list1 to every word in list2.

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-

import codecs

def lev_dist(source, target):
    if source == target:
        return 0


    # Prepare a matrix
    slen, tlen = len(source), len(target)
    dist = [[0 for i in range(tlen+1)] for x in range(slen+1)]
    for i in range(slen+1):
        dist[i][0] = i
    for j in range(tlen+1):
        dist[0][j] = j

    # Counting distance, here is my function
    for i in range(slen):
        for j in range(tlen):
            cost = 0 if source[i] == target[j] else 1
            dist[i+1][j+1] = min(
                            dist[i][j+1] + 1,   # deletion
                            dist[i+1][j] + 1,   # insertion
                            dist[i][j] + cost   # substitution
                        )
    return dist[-1][-1]

# load words from a file into a list
def loadWords(file):
    list = [] # create an empty list to hold the file contents
    file_contents = codecs.open(file, "r", "utf-8") # open the file
    for line in file_contents: # loop over the lines in the file
        line = line.strip() # strip the line breaks and any extra spaces
        list.append(line) # append the word to the list
    return list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print 'Usage: You have to enter a source_word and a target_word'
        sys.exit(-1)
    source, target = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

    # create two lists, one of each file by calling the loadWords() function on the file
    list1 = loadWords(source)
    list2 = loadWords(target)

    # now you have two lists; each file has to have the words you are comparing on the same lines
    # now call you lev_distance function on each pair from those lists

    for i in range(0, len(list1)): # so now you are looping over a range of numbers, not lines
        print lev_dist(list1[0], list2[i])


#    print lev_dist(source, target)
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't reinvent wheels:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: Sometimes good advice - but it's also the best way to learn about how wheels work...

Comment: yes, i know about the module, i just wanted to do it my self to learn python!